# How to read the labels from the x axis of the chart control

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I have a C# WinForms app .Net 4.

It displays a chart control and I would like to read back the date label from the x axis so I can determine if it's a weekend. However I can not find how to access this value.

It's not customlabels but I can find what I should be using to read the value.

```
int weekdayOffset = 0;
foreach (var axisItem in chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels)
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(axisItem);
    if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == ("Saturday"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("its Saturday!");
    }
    weekdayOffset++;
}
```

EDIT:

After much playing i have it working so in case anyone else need to doe the same this is what i have:

```
        int weekdayOffset = 0;

        foreach (var axisItem in chart2.Series[0].Points)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(axisItem.AxisLabel);
            if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == ("Saturday"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("its Saturday!");
            }
            weekdayOffset++;
        }
```

Comment: Generally, the chart is just displaying the data you pass to it.  You should consider getting the information from the raw data and not necessarily the chart x-axis.  It takes a lot of work under the hood to read each data point, parse the string to a datetime stamp and compare it.  Chances are the source from your x-axis is already in a datetime format and you should just be able to check it for a weekend.

Comment: Why not test `chart2.Series[0].Points[index].XValue` ? If it is 0 you should have added the x-values as DataTime, common mistake is to add them formatted as strings..